# Data Bar Color Change

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I would like to format the "Data Bar" in SharePoint to change color based on the percentage. So anything under 25% should be green, 26-50 should be yellow and 51-100 should be light red.

I am aware of the regular conditional formatting but would like to keep the "bar" aspect of the Data Bar.

Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JSON like below to conditionally change the color of data bars:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "=(100 * @currentField) + '%'",
      "style": {
        "padding-left": "8px",
        "white-space": "nowrap"
      }
    }
  ],
  "attributes": {
    "role": "progressbar",
    "aria-valuenow": "@currentField",
    "aria-valuemin": "0",
    "aria-valuemax": "1"
  },
  "style": {
    "padding": "0",
    "color": "black",
    "background-color": "=if(@currentField <= 0.25, '#85b44c', if(@currentField <= 0.5, '#ffc83d', '#c86c70'))",
    "border-top": "='2px solid' + if(@currentField <= 0.25, '#498205', if(@currentField <= 0.5, '#997825', '#a4262c'))",
    "width": "=if(@currentField > 1, '100%', if(@currentField < 0, '0', (100 * @currentField) + '%'))",
    "box-sizing": "border-box"
  }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Here, I am using number column with % applied to it from column settings. So, I am using conditions like <=0.25 and <=0.5. But, you can change the colors and number conditions as per your requirements.

**Documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)